# How can I shift raster layer for making cloud-shadow mask?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinates, cloud-cover

I want to make cloud shadow mask in QGIS. I have raster cloud mask and I have to shift it by X,Y coordinates. Is there any easy solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a very simple solution.

Use either QGIS Translate Raster or GDAL_Translate to create a world-type image (like .bmp, .jpg, .gif or .bil). These rasters don't contain georeference in themselves but rely on a *world file* with the first/last letters of the image and 'w' on the end, thus a jpg has a jgw file, a bitmap (bmp) has a bpw file.

The world file is just a text format (open in notepad) and you can adjust the coordinates easily stepping until it gets in the right spot (usually 4-6 iterations, depending on how good a guesser you are). Read [this to understand the parameters](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcims/9.2/general/topics/author_world_files.htm).

BIL/BSQ files are different to worlded files but the concept is the same, the georeference is in a text format, read [this to learn more](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=BIL,_BIP,_and_BSQ_raster_files).

Alternately you could georeference the cloud mask to the original but that relies on many points of similarity which may or may not be present.