# Click and drag georeferencing

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, move, translate

I am looking for a way to take a group of layers in QGIS and be able to move/geolocate them. I need to offset hundreds of TIFF raster files that are currently in a QGIS group, and I don't have a specific offset for them, I was just looking to be able to click and drag them to a new location. I have tried rasmover, but it is outdated and doesn't work for me, and also have tried freehand raster georeferencer, which does overall what I want, but it wont allow me to move multiple rasters at once, but also the tool does not preserve raster transparency which I need.

Does anyone know of any tools, or any alternative ways to be able to click and drag move a raster, preferably a group of rasters, to a new location?

Comment: All are of these raster suppose to be in the exact same location or do they cover different areas or extents?

Comment: All the rasters I have are small pieces of a larger image, but I need to keep them independent. I am looking to move all of the rater images together as a group, so they don't get moved apart, they need to stay together, but I need to move them all together the same amount.

Comment: Do you know the bounding geometry?  For example, for each raster do you know the coordinates of the corners of each image in the real world coordinate system of your choice?

Comment: I can probably find them, but right now I am not sure I have that information. I was just looking to move the raster images for conceptualization aspects, they don't need to be in a specific location, just a relative location to look nice and be there for understanding a concept.

Comment: Close QGIS, Use something like Python to create world files for each raster just to get images is the 'sort of right location'?  Of course these world files would need to be in the same CRS as your QGIS project.  They when you open QGIS, the images will display where you told them to and still be transparent.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to work with python and was looking for a hopefully simpler solution to this, possibly a tool in the toolbox if possible? does this not exist? or does anyone know where I can find or how I can maybe look into making a tool like this?

Comment: Did you look at this thread?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339477/qgis-how-to-shift-a-raster