Raster origin incorrectly positioned

The raster is from a NC file. The NC file is in the right position, but the raster of it is not.
Is there a way to kind of "reproject" this raster to the same extent as the baselayer?
The CRS is correct (epsg:4326). Is there a calculation process or a workaround to somehow cut off the superfluous part on the right side and place the data on the left side?

Something makes me think the data wasn't in epsg:4326 but some other CRS which has longitude values between 0-360 instead of the -180 +180 (required by epsg:4326)

Thank you! Yes, the values were between 0-360. I cut the raster on the superfluous part and moved it to the left with a script I found (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339477/qgis-how-to-shift-a-raster). Then I merge it back together.
